# SQL Query for log status values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, so basically I have a table (OfferStatusLogs) as described below. I want to count the amount of Offers that had the 'Under Contract' status in any give month, so long as it wasn't subsequently cancelled.

Conditions: If an offer goes under contract twice in a month (first one cancelled) that only counts as one and if an offer goes under contract and is then cancelled  then it doesn't count.

So far I've only been able to get the count of the Under Contract Offers in a month, but don't know how to filter them out if they were cancelled after.

OfferStatusLogs Columns

- ID
- LogStatus
- OfferID
- LogDate

LogStatus Values

- Created
- Under Contract
- Closed
- Cancelled

Current Query:

```
SELECT      max(os.LogDate) AS LastUCDate,
            os.OfferStatusLogType_Type AS LogType, 
            os.OfferStatusLogType_Code AS LogCode

FROM        dbo.OfferStatusLogs AS os
            
WHERE       os.LogStatus = 'Under Contract'

GROUP BY    os.OfferStatusLogType_Type, os.OfferStatusLogType_Code
```

Sample data:

```
ID     LogStatus     LogDate     OfferId
1      Created       2020-01-01  1
2      UnderContract 2020-01-03  1
3      Cancelled     2020-01-04  1
4      Created       2020-01-06  2
5      UnderContract 2020-01-07  2
6      Closed        2020-01-08  2
7      UnderContract 2020-01-10  1
8      Closed        2020-01-11  1
9      Created       2020-01-12  3
10     UnderContract 2020-01-13  3
11     Cancelled     2020-01-14  3
```

Desired Results:

```
Month     UnderContract
Jan, 20   2
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the code looks like SQL Server.  Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: I provided the requested details

Comment: What if it goes under contract and is cancelled in a *later* month?  Is a contract that is  under contract and then closed considered or not?

Comment: No, then it would no longer count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing, this works and produces the desired result.

```
SELECT FORMAT(os.LogDate, 'MMM') + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(os.LogDate) AS varchar) AS [Month], COUNT(*) AS UnderContract 
FROM dbo.OfferStatusLogs os
WHERE os.LogStatus = 'UnderContract' AND os.OfferID NOT IN 
(SELECT OfferID FROM dbo.OfferStatusLogs WHERE OfferID=os.OfferID AND LogDate>os.LogDate AND LogStatus='Cancelled')
GROUP BY FORMAT(os.LogDate, 'MMM') + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(os.LogDate) AS varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i did these followings.

1. Get a count of 'UnderContract' offers in same month
2. Max and Min values of 'UnderContract' and 'Cancelled' values of same offer.
3. Put these in a `CASE WHEN` clause and give them numbers as your conditions and named that new column as `FLAG`.
4. Then sum these values.

```
WITH MAIN AS (
select 1  as id,    'Created' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-01',111) as LogDate, 1 as OfferId union all 
select 2  as id,    'UnderContract' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-03',111) as LogDate, 1 as OfferId union all 
select 3  as id,    'Cancelled' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-04',111) as LogDate, 1 as OfferId union all 
select 4  as id,    'Created' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-06',111) as LogDate, 2 as OfferId union all 
select 5  as id,    'UnderContract' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-07',111) as LogDate, 2 as OfferId union all 
select 6  as id,    'Closed' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-08',111) as LogDate, 2 as OfferId union all 
select 7  as id,    'UnderContract' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-10',111) as LogDate, 1 as OfferId union all 
select 8  as id,    'Closed' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-11',111) as LogDate, 1 as OfferId union all 
select 9  as id,    'Created' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-12',111) as LogDate, 3 as OfferId union all 
select 10 as id,    'UnderContract' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-13',111) as LogDate, 3 as OfferId union all 
select 11 as id,    'Cancelled' as LogStatus, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-14',111) as LogDate, 3 as OfferId  
)
SELECT YEARMONTH,SUM(FLAG) FROM (
SELECT YEARMONTH,OFFERID,CASE WHEN ISUNDER2IN1MONTH>1 AND MINLOGUCIN1M <MINLOGCCIN1M THEN 1 WHEN ISUNDER2IN1MONTH<=1 AND MINLOGUCIN1M<MAXLOGCCIN1M THEN 0  ELSE 1 END FLAG
FROM (
SELECT  OFFERID,convert(varchar(7), LogDate, 126) YEARMONTH,
COUNT(CASE WHEN LOGSTATUS='UnderContract' then 1 else null end) ISUNDER2IN1MONTH,
MAX(CASE WHEN LOGSTATUS='UnderContract' THEN LOGDATE END ) MAXLOGUCIN1M,
MIN(CASE WHEN LOGSTATUS='UnderContract' THEN LOGDATE END )MINLOGUCIN1M,
MAX(CASE WHEN LOGSTATUS='Cancelled' THEN LOGDATE END ) MAXLOGCCIN1M,
MIN(CASE WHEN LOGSTATUS='Cancelled' THEN LOGDATE END )MINLOGCCIN1M
FROM MAIN
  GROUP BY OFFERID,convert(varchar(7), LogDate, 126)
 ) A
  )B
  GROUP BY YEARMONTH
```

[Working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a2f69/35)